# WPF Datagrid edit only single cell value

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I have a WPF Datagrid with 2 columns say parametername and value.

My Requirement is only one value(cell content) for a Particular parametername should be editable and the entire Datagrid contents should be read only....

And I have a save button to save the values.

I had been researching from couple of days for an appropriate solution which observes to be a common requirement in many cases but I havent found...

Please any solution or ideas will be appreciated..

Here is XAML & cs : When the Datagrid loads I want only the PM2 cell value to be in edit mode and all other datagrid content should be greyed out or non-editable..

---

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                     Margin="20,57,18,19" Name="dataGrid1" 
                      Height="250" SelectionUnit="Cell" >

     <DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ParameterName}" Width="100"  Header="Parameter     Name"   IsReadOnly="True"/>

         <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value}" Width="100"  Header="Value" />

        </DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

---

And my CS code

```
public partial class dgSF : Window
{

ObservableCollection<ParameterSet> pmset;

    public dgSF()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pmset = new ObservableCollection<ParameterSet>();

        pmset.Add(new ParameterSet() { ParameterName = "PM1", Value = 10 });

        pmset.Add(new ParameterSet() { ParameterName = "PM2", Value = 50 });

        pmset.Add(new ParameterSet() { ParameterName = "PM3", Value = 70 });

        pmset.Add(new ParameterSet() { ParameterName = "PM4", Value = 80 });

        pmset.Add(new ParameterSet() { ParameterName = "PM5", Value = 100 });

        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = pmset;
    }
}

public class ParameterSet
{

    public string ParameterName { get; set; }

    public int Value { get; set; }

}
```

Thanks So much,

Anu

Comment: So, you want to be able to edit the ParameterName or the Value ?

Comment: I want to edit only the value.

Comment: When the Datagrid loads, from the code behind or from the XAML file i want to get the PM2 cell value in edit mode

Comment: I know this is an old question, but why you do not use _IsReadOnly="false"_ in the Value's column definition?

Answer (score 3):

Use a `DataGridTemplateColumn` and define both `CellTemplate` and `CellEditingTemplate` for the columns you want to be able to edit. For the column you don't want to edit define just the `CellTemplate`

```
  <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                     Margin="20,57,18,19" Name="dataGrid1" 
                      Height="250" SelectionUnit="Cell">

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ParameterName}" Width="100"  Header="Parameter Name" IsReadOnly="True"/>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Editable Value">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            </DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: This adds an extra row to the grid and its still not editable. It appears that the designers of WPF have gone out of their way to make the grid difficult to edit.

Answer (score 1):

simply add one more property to your ParameterSet, eg. public bool IsEditable {get;set;}

then you can use a cell template with a datatrigger on IsEditable to set enabled or not.

EDIT:

```
public class ParameterSet
{
    public ParameterSet()
    {
        IsEditable = false;
    }

    public string ParameterName { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public bool IsEditable { get; set; }

}
```

xaml

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Pmset}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionUnit="Cell" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ParameterName}" Width="100"  Header="Parameter     Name"   IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value}" Width="100"  Header="Value" >
                <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"></Setter>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEditable}" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

in xaml you just declare a style that every cell is not editable, except the ones with IsEditable=true. so every Parameterset with IsEditable =true can be modified.

Comment: I mean how to check in XAML or the cs that the particular value cell corresponds to PM2 and then only set it to edit mode or otherwise not  Thanks,